# Using a value from previous row in a new list entry

Tags: sharepoint-online

Novice user.... 
When I make a new entry of Hours Taken, I need sharepoint to subtract the hours from the "Hours Remaining" listed in the previous row.

In the example in the picture below my next entry of 8 Hours Taken should be subtracted from the 442 Hours Remaining in the previous row.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using quick edit view or sharepoint list form, as this field is auto calculated, you need to create column of type but keep hidden from user input forms and use MS FLOW to update that particular column based on calculation required. Get last item in row and do your calculation.

MS FLOW logic

- Trigger Point - when item is created, we will get reference to CurrentItem(
- Query SharePoint List returning Top and Order by ID desc - Get Items Action (call it LastItemObject)
- Calculate hours - Use Compose action item with subtract method, something like below

  sub(int(LastItemObject.HoursRemaining ), int(CurrentItem.HoursTaken))
- Update current item's  HourRemaining field with output of above compose action.

Answer (score 0):

Like Siddharth suggested I think your requirement can be easily fulfilled using calculated columns. To do this click on add column and select more then on the new screen select calculated. Rest is pretty basic stuff You can see the attached screenshot for more reference. Once you have done selecting all the settings click on OK.
and Viola you problem is solved :)
[image]

The new column would look something like this 
[image]

Hope this helped somebody out there :)

Comment: I currently have this in place. in this case you are inputting 2 separate  values, one for Hours Remaining and one for Hours Taken. I need to count down from 480 hours. when I create a new entry I need to SP to reference the last row showing the most current hours remaining out of the 480. so my only input is the hours taken today to be subtracted from the current Hours Remaining.

Comment: I think this can be done either using flow or sharepoint designer(using workflow) or if you are using Nintex you can refer this article https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint/Getting-the-previous-value-of-a-list-item-after-it-was-modified/td-p/69852